# Work with date and times in CausalImpact

Tags: r

I have a problem for specifying datetime in CausalImpact package.
I hope to use not only date (e.g. 2015-12-02), but also time (e.g. 2015-12-02 16:18:00) for x-axis.

However, I guess we cannot use datetime after I read FormatInputPrePostPeriod code, since Datetime object ("POSIXct", "POSIXt") cannot be converted to either integer or numeric.

I guess one way to around this would be use a plot object generated by CreateImpactPlot function. However, I just wonder if there is another way using CausalImpact only.

Here is the example,

```
time.points <- as.POSIXct(csv_data[,"Time"]) 
x1 <-cbind(csv_data[,3], csv_data[,4])
y <- csv_data[,2]
data <- na.omit(zoo(cbind(y, x1), time.points))

# causal impact
pre.period <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-08-29 00:00:00", "2015-08-29 23:45:00"))
post.period <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-08-30 00:00:00", "2015-08-30 23:45:00")) 

impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)
plot(impact)
```

What I can get from the result is

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

I'd appreciate if you let me know answer for this problem.

Comment: Your question is very unclear IMO but you can convert a `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` class to an integer, because in fact they are doubles with some attributes, see `is.double(as.POSIXct("2015-12-02 16:18:00"))` or `storage.mode(as.POSIXct("2015-12-02 16:18:00"))`

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible example?